# Transactions not ordered fairly? (BSC)

Tags: transactions, bsc, blocks, binance-smart-chain, validators

If we take a look at the [first few transactions](https://bscscan.com/txs?block=29930437&p=7) block [29930437](https://bscscan.com/block/29930437) on Binance smart chain, there is something very interesting going on, if we compare gas prices:

- [Tx 0](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x70833d648efcf11cca615bcef07e2b5d8083e444d51757542d35c088f87cb6b5): The first transaction payed ~2132 Gwei per gas, which is why it is clearly at position 0
- [Tx 1-3](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x73b02230b4b1605090cf52f30fd1253b5b9979ca9f54dabebb2a871502dc5b18): These next transactions spend all the exact same amount of gas (around 16 Gwei)
- [Tx 4](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe099f3c37310c2c8923700d9bf46b6da57d776cec9b985825a6557321fc5f792): Payed ~1312 Gwei

So how did transaction 1-3 get there, considering that they payed a lot las gas than the other transactions around them?
From my understanding, these transaction shouldn't be there if they pay that little amount of gas, unless it is not only gas price validators look at.

I am aware that other factors are typically considered as well, such as when the transaction was received, gas limit etc. But that shouldn't make this much of a difference, is that correct?

Side note: [Tx 2](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x7085582881f7c1e5cdb1add597ebe040d79813aeea05d1604553d3e1fc3f5fe8) also looks like an arbitrage transaction and since transaction 1-3 all payed exactly the same amount of gas, it is likely that these transactions came from the same individual. On Ethereum mainnet, there are implementations like Flashbots, which might explain the ordering but as far as I'm aware, there is no such thing on BSC and transactions should be (relatively fairly ordered).

Comment: There's no rules for ordering transaction in a block. Blocks can be ordered in many ways. The only rule that has to be enforced is that transactions from the same address should be executed by their nonces order.

Comment: I know that there are no fixed rules. But something or someone must have incentivized the validator to put less profitable transactions before the more profitable ones (which does not usually happen). I would like to know what or who has likely done that.